# Maven Antrun Plugin inheritance

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a maven multi module project structure.
I want to build the jar of a child project using maven-antrun-plugin by declaring it inside the parent project's pom.

Here is my parent-pom:

```
<groupId>com.package.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>concat-build-classpath</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>

                                <jar destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                                    basedir="src/main">
                                    <manifest>
                                        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.package.abc.Application" /> 
                                    </manifest>
                                </jar>

                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>never</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>unwanted</finalName>
                            <classifier>unwanted</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build></project>
```

and here is my child project's pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.package.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <finalName>sample-project</finalName>
</build></project>
```

When I am building child project it shows the error as:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project sample-project: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Why are you using maven-antrun-plugin? And not keeping the convention and let Maven do the work ? What kind of problem are you trying to resolve? Do not use a plugin in the parent pom..Do you have a full example of your project somewhere (like github etc.?)

Comment: @khmarbaise While I create the jar of the child project(i.e, sample-project in this example), I want to edit the class-path attribute of its manifest file. The class-path attribute lists all the required dependent-jars. I want to prepend some jar names with 'folder1/' and some with 'folder2/'. For this I am using maven-antrun-plugin.
There are many projects in which I want this to happen. So, I have created a parent project(i.e, parent-pom project in this example) and added the antrun plugin in its pom and all the projects are now referencing this parent-pom.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `<inherited>` to false in `<plugin>` element:

```
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
   <inherited>false</inherited>
   ...
```

More info at:

- https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugins
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_inherited_Tag_In_Build_Plugins